# appear noise in decrypted image after send the corresponding encrypted image over socket python

Tags: python, sockets, encryption, tcp

I have a program consisting of two projects (client\server), the server sends an encrypted image to the client, after receiving the image, decrypted under the same key in encryption. but the problem, when the original image is retrieved after the decryption procedure, some noises appear in it. these noises don't appear when the encryption and decryption perform on the same python project.
note: both projects operate on the same host.
on another side, I take a copy of the encrypted image and put it on another project, after decrypted it, also, the noises appear again. so, the (send\receive) code of the socket between client and server doesn't the main reason for this corruption.
what are the major problems ?.

at the client:

```
fil = open('Data\Iot.bmp', "wb")
            length = int(sock.recv(1024).decode())
            for i in range(length):
                img1 = sock.recv(1024)
                fil.write(img1)
            fil.close()
```

at the server:

```
img = open('Data\Original_img.bmp', "rb")
    im = []
    l = img.read(1024)
    while l:
        im.append(l) #dividing the image into blocks, and put them into a list, each block (1024) bytes.
        l = img.read(1024)
    img.close()

    sock.send(str(len(im)).encode())

    for i in im:
        sock.send(i)
```

[here is the original image:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tn98q.png)

[here the decrypted image after received:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMCJ7.png)

Comment: probably a silly question but you sure its tcp? Or any config different on either machine (related to the executing code)?

Comment: Since it works on the same machine, most likely you screwed up the socket transmission